# Unity ArKit game object problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

I built my project out using the unity arkit plugin. My game objects load, but I can't walk around them. When I try to get close to the game objects, they move away and get smaller. Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I changed it, but I can’t be any clearer with my problem.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try to provide a minimal code example.

Comment: That’s what I think my problem is. I’m missing the code. I can’t provide code if I don’t know it or it’s missing out of the example file within the plugin. I’m learning as I go. Do you know the answer?

Comment: Hello and wellcome.
I'm new too using ARKit but, for me, it sounds like the calibration points.

ARKit relies in points taken from the enviroment, if you walk arround your GO and you can't view it from every perspective then, maybe, your enviroment laks of enought calibration points.

Some times I suffer from the same trouble but it gets solved once I change my test location, in the street or garden maybe, remember that the real world light must be bright enought.

For my test I use the ARKit example that cames in the Unity package. That scene works for you?

Comment: Salvador, thanks for the reply. I load the arkit plugin preset example into my hierarchy and build out. I think I am missing something. Although I suspect you may be correct on test location. I test it in a well lit room with carpet. I noticed my plane detection is not vey good.